# what is the syntax for "or" inside an if statement?

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, conditional-statements

I could probably use multiple else if statements, but is there a simpler and cleaner way to do an if (condition or othercondition..) in objective-c?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (condition || othercondition)
{
    // ...
}
```

That's two pipe characters (`|`), if it isn't too clear.

Answer (score 6):

Just like in C, C++, or Java, a double-pipe will do the trick for you:

```
if (condition1 || condition2) {
    // code here
}
```